# How to get distinct values in my dropdown list MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, distinct, html.dropdownlistfor

I just stuck up with the issue, i am fetching data from database using entity framework, but facing problems.

**Problem**

My **Role** table has multiple `Roles`, it contains duplicate values like `others` 4 times, i am fetching it and binding it to dropdown, but i am getting `others` value 4 times in dropdown list

Here is the code that i am trying.

```
public List<RefrenceDataModel> GetJobRoles()
{
    List<RefrenceDataModel> lstRefrenceDataReturn = new List<RefrenceDataModel>();
    DataContext context = new DataContext();
    lstRefrenceDataReturn = context.JobsRoles.ToList().distinct().Select(items => new RefrenceDataModel() { RefrenceDataName = items.RoleName, RefrenceDataID = items.RoleID }).ToList<RefrenceDataModel>();
    return lstRefrenceDataReturn;
}
```

This code is returning duplicate values, but i don't want duplicates, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `Distinct(your implementation of IEqualityComparer<T>)`

Comment: I expect it's not working because your `RefrenceDataModel` type does not implement `IEquatable<RefrenceDataModel>` properly or at all. (And as a side note, is `RefrenceDataModel` spelt right? ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using GroupBy

```
lstRefrenceDataReturn = context.JobsRoles
  .GroupBy(r => r.RoleName)
  .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
  .Select(items => new RefrenceDataModel() { RefrenceDataName = items.RoleName, RefrenceDataID = items.RoleID }).ToList<RefrenceDataModel>();
```

Comment: Tried `.Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())` instead `.Select(g => g.First())` and it worked... Thanks Damith

Comment: @DhavalMarthak That's better.